# How to declare plugin dependencies

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

My plugin needs `jquery-ui` plugin to run. How do I declare this in the plugin's `BuildConfig.groovy`?

I'm expecting that `grails install-plugin /my/plugin.zip` should install `jquery-ui` as well. This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
plugins {
    compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to "refresh-dependencies". Also sometimes I find I need to issue a "clean", exit the shell, and restart and it will pick up the added plugin

Comment: @Alidad no error when i'm installing my plugin. i can just see that `jquery-ui` doesn't get installed (not listed by `list-plugins` and when i do `<r:require module='jquery-ui' />` the module is not found.

Comment: @user2264997 tried `refresh-dependencies` but `jquery-ui` doesn't get installed... my plugin gets installed by not `jquery-ui`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in Grails 2.2.x, I suspect that you are having  the new Grails resolve dependency resolution mechanism which results into issues explained [here](http://www.objectpartners.com/2013/02/13/grails-2-2-publishing-your-plugins-as-maven-artifacts-to-resolve-dependency-resolution-issues/) by @sconnelly and [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html) in the Dependency resolution section.

Assuming your first plugin is using jquery ui and probably resource plugin and all your modules are correctly defined in plugin resources configuration(myResources.groovy) file, for quick fix try to set legacyResolve = true in your application buildConfig. I made a small example [here](https://github.com/alidadasb/jQueryUI) 
Let me know if this resolved your issue

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way of declaring dependencies. Don't use `install-plugin` since it's a deprecated command.

What you may be missing is to declare the jquery-ui in your view:

```
<r:require module="jquery-ui"/>
```

This will add the javascript and css files of JQuery UI.

Comment: would be using `install-plugin` stop my plugin's dependencies from being installed? that doesn't sound right... i didn't forget to `r:require` the module, in fact i get an error that the module doesn't exist when i do. if i install `jquery-ui` after/before installing my plugin all is well. it is just that my plugin does not install it for me.

Comment: i installed my plugin using `grails.plugin.location` in the app's `BuildConfig.groovy`... still the same problem - i have to install `jquery-ui` plugin by hand, it does not get installed by my plugin.

Comment: Probably you're missing `legacyResolve true` that's needed for grails.plugin.location.